# User Register With Rest Api on Swift Key Not Found Error

Tags: ios, mysql, json, swift

I am trying to perform user registration and user login operations with rest api in a swift project. I am using generic api service while doing the operation. I have a model and a mvvm pattern.

When trying to register the user, I get the following error.

```
Failed to serialize json: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"name\", intValue: nil) (\"name\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

I share with you my ApiService, Model and Mvvm pages.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

ApiService

```
enum HTTPMethod: String {
    case get = "GET"
    case post = "POST"
}

struct ApiService {
    static let shared = ApiService()

    func fetchData<T: Codable>(url: String, method: HTTPMethod, completion: @escaping (T) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Filed to fetch home feed:", error)
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(user)
                }
            } catch let jsonError {
                print("Failed to serialize json:", jsonError)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Model

```
struct RegisterModel: Codable {
    var name: String
    var email: String
    var password: String
}
```

View Model

```
struct RegisterViewModel {
    let register: RegisterModel
    
    init(register: RegisterModel) {
        self.register = register
    }
    
    var name: String {
        return self.register.name
    }
    
    var email: String {
        return self.register.email
    }
    
    var password: String {
        return self.register.password
    }
}
```

View Controller Function

```
extension RegisterViewController {
    // User Register
    func userRegister() {
        let url = "http://localhost:5050/auth/register"
        ApiService.shared.fetchData(url: url, method: .post) { (register: RegisterModel) in
            self.registerViewModel = RegisterViewModel(register: register)

            print("Data:\(String(describing: register))")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.objects.nameTextField.text = register.name
                self.objects.emailTextField.text = register.email
                self.objects.passwordTextField.text = register.password
                print("User Data: \(String(describing: self.registerViewModel))")
                print(self.objects.nameTextField.text = self.registerViewModel?.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Json Code

```
const Joi = require("@hapi/joi");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../models/User");
const Token = require("../models/ResetToken");
const sendEmail = require("../utils/sendEmail");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const config = require('./../dbconfig');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const { now } = require("mongoose");
const { string } = require("@hapi/joi");
const { schema, db } = require("../models/User");
const { request } = require("http");
const { response } = require("express");
const connection = mysql.createConnection(config.dbOptions);

const JWTSecret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
const bcryptSalt = process.env.BCRYPT_SALT;
const clientURL = process.env.CLIENT_URL;

// Register User Controller 
const registerController = async (req, res) => {
    const rc = req.body;
    const email = rc.email;
    const password = rc.password;
    const nowDate = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '');
    // Salting
    const saltRounds = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);

    // Insert Query
    const insertQuery = `INSERT INTO users (name, surname, email, password, profile_image, role, 
        account_type, created_date, updated_date) VALUES ('`+rc.name+`','`+rc.surname+`',
        '`+rc.email+`','`+encryptedPassword+`','`+rc.profile_image+`','`+rc.role+`', '`+rc.account_type+`',
        '`+nowDate+`','`+nowDate+`');`

    // Joi Validation    
    const registerSchema = Joi.object().keys({
        name: Joi.string().required().min(3).max(255),
        surname: Joi.string().required().min(3).max(255),
        email: Joi.string().required().email().min(3).max(255),
        password: Joi.string().required().min(6).max(255),
        profile_image: Joi.string(),
        role: Joi.string(),
        account_type: Joi.string()
    });

    // Select Query
    const query = `SELECT COUNT (*) AS cnt FROM users WHERE email = ?`
    connection.query(query, email, function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            if (data[0].cnt > 0) {
                res.send("Email Already Exist!");
            } else {
                if (registerSchema.validate(rc).error) {
                    res.send(registerSchema.validate(rc).error.details);
                } else {
                    connection.query(insertQuery, function(err, data) {
                        try {
                            if (err) {
                                res.send("Query is not showing!");
                            } else {
                                res.send("Success: Data successfully saved to database.");
                            }
                        } catch (e) {
                            console.log(e);
                            res.send(400);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Without knowing the JSON it's pretty hard to guess the solution. An *educated guess* is an ignored umbrella struct.

Comment: The mostly likely cause of this is malformed JSON from your API (or simply JSON that is not what you expect). Update your question to include the JSON sent back by the server.

Comment: @idz i added my json code.

Comment: No, I mean the string representation of `data` returned from the `dataTask`.

Comment: Use `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` for this.

Comment: @vadian do you mean this
{
    "name": "user name",
    "email": "name@mail.com",
    "password": "123456",
}

Comment: @idz What should i do?

Comment: I not really that well up on node, or the library you are using, but first you need -- like all the comments are telling you -- to understand what the server is returning to you, so print out the JSON you receive and **check for errors**. Next you need to understand how to return the (possibly newly) inserted user record from your server.

Comment: You should add the json string you receive to the question _exactly_ as it’s printed. The reason I say exactly because I see an extra comma at the end in the one you posted in a comment which would mean the json isn’t valid. So we really need to see the actual json you receive.

Comment: Replace `print("Failed to serialize json:", jsonError)`, with `print("Failed to serialize json:", jsonError); print("Received response: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")`, and give us that output.

Comment: @Larme Receive response: Optional("{\"code\":\"ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR\",\"errno\":1054,\"sqlMessage\":\"Unknown column \'register\' in \'where clause\'\",\"sqlState\":\"42S22\",\"index\":0,\"sql\":\"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=register\"}")

Comment: @JoakimDanielson When i fetch the user data, my json output is like this;

{"id": 404,"name": "dene","surname": "dene",
        "email": "deneme@hotmail.com", "password": "$2a$10$7mVCZU.2JJKiMQt8CBfR3OcRSdRT1oQ1V.YLo2FCuen9bwjckzld.","
profile_image": "profile.jpg","reset_password": null,"reset_password_expires": null,"role": "user","account_type": "undefined","token": null, "created_date": "2023-03-07T15:55:36.000Z", "updated_date": "2023-03-07T15:55:36.000Z"
    }

Comment: Now you give us two completely different json strings as the response which doesn’t make it easy to understand what is going on. We are only interested in what happens on the client side since this question is about your iOS, swift code so I assume the first version that you responded to @Larme with is what is received by the swift code and that means that what you send from the server isn’t the expected data but an sql error message. If I am right in this this isn’t a iOS/swift question but a server question which mean you need to rewrite it and change the tags.

Comment: According to your two different output, I'd say this. "Receive response:..." That's what you really are receiving. Is your request wrong (wrong parameters, missing value, etc.), "When i fetch the user data, my json output is like this" That's what you are supposed to send back. Clarify your current situation.

Comment: @Larme 
Receive response: Optional("{\"code\":\"ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR\",\"errno\":1054,\"sqlMessage\":\"Unknown column \'register\' in \'where clause\'\",\"sqlState\":\"42S22\",\"index\":0,\"sql\":\"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=register\"}")

Comment: @Larme I gave you the result you wanted. This is the output of the program when I fill in the name, e-mail and password fields on the form screen.

Comment: @Larme When I want to register a user through Postman, I can register without any problems. When I try this from my form field in my Swift program, I get an error.

Comment: Ask Postman to generate Swift code (might be bad Swift code, but could help see a diff), or ask it to share cURL code, and share it with us ? But it's unclear. You are currently doing a simple GET on the URL with no parameters?

Comment: @Larme This is my url "http://localhost:5050/auth/register" and i am using "POST".

Comment: In Swift, you are using GET, just to say...

Comment: @Larme i fixet it. I also tried both get or post methods, I wonder what answer it will give. In the end it gives the same error.

Comment: You don't use the POST parameter. You are calling `dataTask(with URL:)` instead of `dataTask(with URRequest:)`, where `URLRequest` can have parameters and method (POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, etc.), while when you use `URL`, it des a GET.